# cannot create XML well formed document

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

What am I doing wrong? It is giving me error

[Xerces-J 2.9.1] Checking "Task3.xml" for Well-formedness ... Ln 8 Col 24 - Open quote is expected for attribute associated with an  element type  . 1 Error

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->

<customer customnumber=1 xsi:schemaLocation="Task3.xsd">
    <name>Jack Smith</name>
    <email>jacksmith@123456.com</email>    
    <order ordernumber=1>
        <orderdate>01-JAN-2016</orderdate>
        <handling-cost>100</handling-cost>
        <product productnumber=1>
            <name>computer</name>
            <price>1000</price>
        </product>
        <product productnumber=2>
            <name>piano</name>
            <price>100000</price>
        </product>
    </order>
    <order ordernumber=2>
        <orderdate>03-JUN-2016</orderdate>
        <handling-cost>1000</handling-cost>
        <product productnumber=2>
            <name>piano</name>
            <price>20000</price>
        </product>
        <product productnumber=4>
            <name>viollin</name>
            <price>10000</price>
        </product>
    </order>
</customer>
```

Please help me correct this. What should I change or alter?

Answer (score 2):

XML attributes need to be surrounded with quotes, either:

```
<order ordernumber="2">
```

or

```
<order ordernumber='2'>
```

You are also using an undeclared namespace prefix. You need to declare it:

```
<customer customnumber="1" xsi:schemaLocation="Task3.xsd"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Comment: its giving me this error now The prefix "xsi" for attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" associated with an element type "customer" is not bound.
1 Error

Comment: You have to add the namespace for xsd -> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"